# Separate Buttons to track separate values [python]

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a rudimentary python program for tracking bullet fire in my local Rogue Trader campaign. I hate writing - erasing - rewriting on my sheet leaving it smudged and gross. This gives me an excuse to practice my coding skills. Eventually going to have it save values to a file and then read them upon start up, but that's in the future.

I am letting it ask for what guns I have, setting a clipSize for said gun, and then create a button that references each gun. Upon pressing the button, fireGun is supposed to take the value of the gun shot corresponding to which button is pressed. However, the way it runs currently, all guns fire from the same ammo amount which is the last 'clipSize' entered.

I need each button to track its own variable to update the correct dictionary reference upon fireGun.

```
from tkinter import *

addGuns = 'true'
gunList = {}


while (addGuns == 'true'):

    newGun = input("What is the name of your gun? ")
    clipSize = int(input("What is its clip size? "))
    gunList[newGun] = clipSize 
    gunCheck = input("Done adding guns? ")
    if (gunCheck == 'yes'):
        addGuns = 'false'

root = Tk()
root.title("Pew Pew")

def fireGun(x):
    startingAmmo = gunList[x]
    endingAmmo = startingAmmo - 1
    gunList[x] = endingAmmo
    print(gunList[x])
    return

for gun in gunList:
    button = Button(root, text = gun, command = lambda name = gun:fireGun(gun))
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use partial to send parameters to a function with a command= call. You could also use an Entry to get the gun info, and one label for each gun with the name and updated ammo amount on each label.  A very sloppy example (I have to go to work).

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

gunCheck="no"
gunList = {}

while gunCheck != 'yes':
    newGun = input("What is the name of your gun? ")
    clipSize = int(input("What is its clip size? "))
    gunList[newGun] = int(clipSize)
    gunCheck = input("----->Done adding guns? ")
##    if (gunCheck == 'yes'):
##        addGuns = 'false'

root = Tk()
root.title("Pew Pew")

def fireGun(x):
    startingAmmo = gunList[x]
    endingAmmo = startingAmmo - 1
    gunList[x] = endingAmmo
    print(gunList[x])
    label_list[x].config(text=x + "-->" + str(endingAmmo))
    return

label_list={}
fr=Frame(root)
fr.pack(side="top")
for gun in gunList:
    lab=Label(fr, text="%s --> %d" %(gun, gunList[gun]))
    lab.pack(side=TOP) 
    label_list[gun]=lab
    button = Button(root, text = gun, command = partial(fireGun, gun))
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ooooh. Awesome. I'm still learning python. So the %() and partial are new things to me. Always more to learn.